# Sending cookies using spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cookies, session-cookies

So, I'm trying to send cookies to my frontend and I'm not using spring security. When the user enter their name and click submit button, I want that info to be send to my spring and then I want to return the info of the user and cookie. I implemented the logic like this

```
@PostMapping("/addUser")
public User addUser(@RequestBody String name, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

HttpSession getSession = (HttpSession) request.getAttribute("session");
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("sessionId", getSession.getId());
response.addCookie(cookie);

sessionService.addSession(getSession);

String session = (String) getSession.getId();
System.out.println("Session id is " + session);
User newUser = new User(name, session);
userService.addUser(newUser);

return newUser;
```

}

to check if cookie is working correctly, I'm using this method

```
@PostMapping("/noOfUsers")
public int userCount(@RequestBody String sessionId, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    System.out.println(request.getSession().getId());
     Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
     if (cookies != null) {
            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
              if (cookie.getName().equals("sessionId")) {
                 System.out.println(cookie.getValue());
              }
            }
          }


    return this.userService.noOfUser();
}
```

I know you people might say "use get mapping" well I want to send my user account too when checking that's why I'm using postmapping where I will be sending my username too.

So, coming back to question. Well, I did try using postman and it worked I got the cookie value as I should have but when working with frontend, it just didn't worked which made me question am I doing it in right way??

Comment: did you check if the browser reported some errors? e.g. chrome requires some additional attributes in the cookie otherwise it will be blocked.

Comment: @sge, I just wanted to know if its the correct way or not to send cuz I'm using angular as my frontend tool and I still haven't figured out how to accept the cookie in it. Did a lot of research but google just keeps recommending the same one that doesn't work.